# New to Python, implementing a function using a string as an input

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and one of the problems I have for homework has me stuck.

Here's the question?
Implement function cheer() that takes as input a team name (as a string) and prints a cheer as shown:

```
cheer(‘Huskies’)
```

How do you spell winner?
I know, I know!
H U S K I E S !
And that's how you spell winner!
Go Huskies!

I've been able to get everything figured out except for the spaced out team name on the third line. I'll post what I have below. If anyone had any ideas how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it?

```
def cheer(team):
    print("How do you spell winner?"+"\nI know, I know!""\n"+team.upper()+"!"+"\nAnd that's how you spell winner!"+"\nGo "+ team+"!"+"\n")
```

Using the team name "Devils" as the input, this is what the above code gets me:

```
cheer("Devils")
How do you spell winner?
I know, I know!
DEVILS!
And that's how you spell winner!
Go Devils!
```

Comment: @unutbu has a good answer/hint. In case it's not obvious, he's suggesting you look at the str.join() function for doing the spacing (http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 6):

You can add a space between each letter using [str.join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
In [22]: team = 'Huskies'

In [23]: ' '.join(team.upper())
Out[23]: 'H U S K I E S'
```

or, to include the exclamation point,

```
In [27]: ' '.join(team.upper()+'!')
Out[27]: 'H U S K I E S !'
```

Comment: Are you sure this is, pedagogically, the most helpful answer?  The OP is most likely studying loops.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to iterate over elements in a string is to use what are known as list comprehensions in python, you can read more about them here:

[List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

In your example, you want to iterate over each item in a string, append a space, then concatenate those results back together using a join. This can be done in a single line of code in python:

```
("".join([s + ' ' for s in team])).upper()
```

Dissecting this code, I'm doing several things in a single line:

1) Iterating through each letter in the string, and appending a space

2) That iteration returns a list, so I join that list with an empty string, which gives a single string

3) Convert that string to upper case

Comment: Of course unutbu's answer is way better and simpler. Doh. Haven't had coffee yet.